# what does "the condition is met" exactly mean in programming languages?

Tags: javascript

> A conditional statement is based on concept of if/then/else ; if a condition is met , then your code executes one or more statements , else your code does something different

I encountered this statement and don't understand what "meeting the condition" means.

Comment: `if (the pope is catholic) print("The condition has been met!") else print ("The condition was not met")`

Comment: It's another wording for "the condition is true" or "the logical expression evaluates to true".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part in brackets in the `if` statement is the condition. For example, in

```js
if (x == 5)
```

the condition is `x == 5`. The condition being "met" basically means "if the expression evaluates to true" (so here, if the value of `x` is 5). In Javascript it's a little more complicated than that, because the condition doesn't have to be an actual Boolean expression. Based on the result of the expression, the following evaluation takes place:

- Undefined => false
- Null => false
- Boolean => the value (so true => true, false => false)
- Number => true for any number except 0, -0, or NaN, false for those
- String => true for any non-empty string, false otherwise
- Symbol => true
- BigInt => true for any non-zero value
- Object => true

If the result of *that* is true, then the condition is met and the body of the `if` statement is executed. Otherwise, the body of the `else` part is executed if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

the if instruction is evaluating whatever is inside the parenthesis, if the condition inside the parenthesis is true then the if statemen is executed, otherwise the else statement is executed

```
var = 5;
if( var === 5)
{
  alert("this is shown because var equals 5")
}
else
{
  alert("this will never show unless you change var or the condition inside the if parenthesis")
}
```